# How to choose solutions for secure messaging front-end and HIPAA compliant database?

Tags: java, php, sql, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am interesting a setting up a small business website, the front-end of which will be a customer portal (secure messaging center) with perhaps the ability to upload images. E-commerce capability will be needed, using Paypal and CC (US only). The back-end will be a database and the whole system will need to be HIPAA compliant.

I was wondering what platform should this be built on? Are there off-the shelf modules/libraries for secure messaging (I expect there are for e-commerce) and the database?  I have experience programming Java but only on Android, as well as Swift on iOS -- wrote a couple of apps -- including the built-in SQLite features.

If I decide to contract this out, as it's most likely, I would like to have a sense of what type of programming or packages are needed. Would PHP/MySQL fit the bill? 
Can you point me in the right direction so I can educate myself?

Comment: Frankly security an HIPAA compliance are much more than simply choice of tools.
Any popular web stack, properly implemented, should be capable of compliance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a HIPAA compliant storage option in Microsoft Azure, you should probably look into [Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/introduction).

It provides SDKs for different programming languages, easy to query and manage. As it is widely used for SaaS based applications, it has almost all type of [security compliance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/azure-compliance-documentdb-certified-for-iso-27001-hipaa-and-the-eu-model-clauses/) incorporated.

Look [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-cosmosdb-secure-private-compliant/) for list of security compliance provided for Azure Cosmos DB.